# How many points are midpoints?

Tags: algorithm, point

Given a list of coordinates, I would like to know how to know how many points are in the middle of two other points.

```
A(1 ; 3)
B(2 ; 2)
C(3 ; 1)
D(3 ; 2)
E(3 ; 3)
```

Here is a representation:

```
_______
|A| |E|  
_______
| |B|D|  
_______
| | |C|  
_______
```

Here B and D are midpoints, so the answer is "2".

I've found a very inefficient `O(n³)` algorithm.

```
count := 0
For each point x1  
  For each point x2   
    For each point x3  
      If x3 is the midpoint of [x1;x2] 
        count := count + 1
Print count
```

Do you have any idea about a more efficient algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a **[k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)**, you can improve it to `O(n^2 logn)`:

Store each point in the tree, and for each pair (there are `O(n^2)` of those), search if there exists a point in the middle of them (easy to calculate where the middle is). Each seek is `O(logn)` resulting in `O(n^2 * log(n))` solution.

If you are talking about **integers only, you might increase the complexity to `O(n^2)`** on average by placing the points in a **[hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)** (as pairs), and check if there exists an element with the desired coordinates.

(Note, the two solutions are basically the same, the only variation is the implementation of the set, one uses a tree and the other uses a hash table).

**Pseudo code:**

```
set <- new set
for each point p:
   set.add(p)
for each point p1:
   for each point p2 != p1:
       candidate <- findMiddle(p1,p2)
       if set.contains(candidate):
           yield (p1,candidate,p2)
```